# What is the difference between chroot command and chroot() system call

Tags: chroot

Can anyone help in making me understand, what's the real difference between chroot command and chroot() system call.

Comment: I think that is the top stupid question for today.

Comment: The question is quite clear, and entirely appropriate.

Comment: Well, ok, the answer would be then: The same one as between mkdir() system call and mkdir command.

Comment: Ingo, I dont think its a stupid question. If you are not  aware, i found the answer for it and found that ,there is a security hole while using chroot() as a system call which is not the same case with use of chroot command. chroot mechanism is used to sandbox a system(Mainly unix) , so that a untested code can be executed in an isolated enviorment. chroot() allows to get out of this environment and may damage secure files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A system call is a means for a program to interact with the kernel.

A unix tool command is either a small stand alone program (in this case) or else a shell built in (in some other cases).  This allows a user or a script to perform operations without having to provide low level program code for doing so.

Where a command and a system call have the same name, typically the command provides a way to accomplish the functionality of the system call, or something similar.

System calls are documented in section 2 of the manual, while commands may be elsewhere such as page 8.  So if you type

`man 2 chroot` you will get the documentation for the system call

and if you type

`man 8 chroot` (or in many cases simply fail to specify a page) you will get the documentation for the command.

if you type

`which chroot` you will find the location of the executable which implements the command, assuming it is in your search path as it usually would be.